# Is there a way to disable Mapbox-gl from zooming on triggering GeolocateControl?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

I'm trying to disable zooming on user location while triggering GeolocateControl.
Basically I do not want to run `map.flyTo()` function while locating an user.

```
const geolocate = useRef( new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true,
    showAccuracyCircle: false
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map.current.addControl(geolocate.current);
geolocate.current.on('geolocate', function(e) {
    map.current.flyTo({
        zoom: map.current.getZoom()
    });
});
```

Okay, I figured out a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The following involves overriding the `_updateCamera` function of the `GeolocateControl` to customize its behavior, effectively preventing the default zoom to the user's location.

```
geolocate.current._updateCamera = () => {};
```